# How to check which sections of a site are tracked by Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, tracking

I'm currently managing a PHP website that "integrates" several independent modules under the same domain. And by independent I mean that they don't share common templates, some small parts even being static HTML pages.

Where it's present, the Google Analytics code is [included the proper way](http://pastie.org/3699506).

In such a scenario, how can one check which how much of the site does Google Analytics actually track, and even more important how do I find the pages/sections that are not tracked yet?

---

P.S.: [Trying with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6328483/341929), this is the output I get:

```
$ curl my-site.com | grep -c google-analytics.com
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12982    0 12982    0     0  11844      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 20221
0
```

Comment: you could open all files with an editor and search for the script. I don't know a better way. How many files are that, that it would be so difficult to check them?

Comment: @DRP96 there's quite a bit of spagetti in that code, that's why I'm interested if there's another way to test this. Maybe crawling the end result?

Comment: Well maybe there is another possibility, but I currently don't know anyone.. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

To audit the tracking of your site you have a few tools (not exactly free however)

[WASP](http://webanalyticssolutionprofiler.com/)

[ObservePoint](http://www.observepoint.com/)

The only valid method would be to crawl the whole site with a JavaScript enabled crawler and check that every page fires a hit.

You could also have some creative strategies (depending on what you can change or not on this site):

- Add a second tracker over the whole site (for example as an external JS called everywhere, you can even use an existing resource and append the code for GA in it. After a few days of collection, you export hostnames and pages tracked by the 2 systems and you'll find what's not tracked and needs to be fixed
- If you have some control over the existing code, you can combine an external JS at the bottom of the page, doing the default tracking on the same UA-XXXX-YY, but firing only when the inline code wasn't present above (you set var tracked = true inline, and test 'tracked' in the external JS before firing a pageview)

How does it sounds to you ?

Answer (score 0):

I like using [Screaming Frog](http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/) to audit which pages have GA code vs which don't. This is only an option on the paid version, but they make it very easy to do a custom search, so I'll typically run two simultaneously while spidering the site - one asking for a report of which pages *do* have GA code and one asking for the pages that don't.